# How to deal with the internal error in play framework 2, Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern

Tags: exception, playframework-2.0, internal

i just finished an very simply echo program, send the name to the server, and then send it back to the client. But here is the problem:

The name should be encode with UTF-8 first, like`%xy%xy%...`

Then we send it to the server: `myhost:9000/send/%xy%xy...`

the method is like:

```
public static Result send(final String name)
{
...
}
```

If the data is correct, it can be decoded successfully without any exceptions and errors.
But sometimes, the encoded name may be invalid, such as `%20%A`. As a result, it can not be decoded and cause an **internal error**. The process cannot even get into the "send" method.

**I want to know how can I catch this error when I enter the url `myhost:9000/send/%20%A, and then send the result(assume it is "wrong name") back to the client?**

The exceptions are:

```
 Unexpected exception
IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern
 java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:187)
 play.api.mvc.PathBindable$$anon$9.bind(Binders.scala:365)
 play.api.mvc.PathBindable$$anon$9.bind(Binders.scala:364)
 play.core.Router$RouteParams$$anonfun$fromPath$1.apply(Router.scala:1036)
 play.core.Router$RouteParams$$anonfun$fromPath$1.apply(Router.scala:1036)
 scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133)
 play.core.Router$RouteParams.fromPath(Router.scala:1036)
 Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.apply(routes_routing.scala:179)
 Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.apply(routes_routing.scala:87)
 scala.PartialFunction$$anon$3.apply(PartialFunction.scala:67)
 scala.PartialFunction$$anon$3.apply(PartialFunction.scala:66)
 play.core.Router$Routes$class.handlerFor(Router.scala:1251)
 Routes$.handlerFor(routes_routing.scala:14)
 play.api.GlobalSettings$$anonfun$onRouteRequest$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Global.scala:64)
 play.api.GlobalSettings$$anonfun$onRouteRequest$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Global.scala:63)
 scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:146)
 play.api.GlobalSettings$$anonfun$onRouteRequest$1.apply(Global.scala:63)
 play.api.GlobalSettings$$anonfun$onRouteRequest$1.apply(Global.scala:63)
 scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:146)
 play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onRouteRequest(Global.scala:63)
 play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onRouteRequest(Global.scala:120)
 play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$sendHandler$1$1.apply(Server.scala:60)
 play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$sendHandler$1$1.apply(Server.scala:59)
 scala.Either$RightProjection.map(Either.scala:285)
 play.core.server.Server$class.sendHandler$1(Server.scala:59)
 play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:89)
 play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:88)
 scala.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:277)
 play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:88)
 play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:38)
 play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:226)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:563
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:366)
 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:568)
 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:437)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:563)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:91)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:373)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:247)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: How do you decode the string ?

Comment: String name = URLEncoder.encode("[a啊]", "UTF-8") ; the name will be %5Ba%E5%95%8A%5D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a BodyPraser as described in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaBodyParsers)

This will allow you to manually validate the encoding and return the proper errors to the user.

Comment: But I think BodyParser is only suit for 'POST' while I am using 'GET'.